# Southeast Beast Facility

Tags: construction, secret-society

There is a giant facility called the Genetic Forge.  It's a giant facility that uses supercomputers to modify human zygote genomes. In order to understand the DNA and how to change it properly, they need to engage in some horrific and super unethical experiments, and keep these abominations alive to study them. So my question is what would be the best place to put this facility?

When answering keep these factors in mind...

- it's as long as the Boeing's Everett factory and as tall as the Burj Khalifa
- it needs to be in the southeast region  of the US
- cannot be submerged in water
- lots of noise and supercomputers
- cannot be discovered in mass

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75229/discussion-on-question-by-user45751-southeast-beast-facility).

Comment: It seems to me the question is:  How to hide a huge facility in the US southwest.  If you can reword this to make that more clear, we can reopen your question.

Comment: This has been edited and nominated for reopening, but it's not ready.  The approximate volume of this building is an astronomical, unrealistic, and unbelievable 11.8 BILLION cubic feet.  It can't be hid anywhere.  The power requirements alone point a massive arrow toward it.  Supplying the facility would be like (literally!) supplying New York City.  You'd be able to see this thing from space.  It's not worth fixing the question because the size of the building makes it physically impossible to hide.

Answer (score 5):

Underground.

Preferable under a shell factory/facility so the power use can be hidden and waste disposed of

I'd use a meat processing plant. You already have noise, power, food and a great way to get rid of dead bodies especially if the plant process pigs. The plants already have high security for hygiene and to keep out animal rights do-gooders.

If the workers are actually custom humans, the chance of discovery would be incredibly low.

Only issue is the occasional health inspector who would be only looking at the visible parts.

Comment: "*as long as the Boeing's Everett factory and as tall as the Burj Khalifa*" that pretty much wipes out "underground".

Comment: You can go 100 stories underground.

Comment: The workers aren't custom humans but they are not US citizens either, and most of the work is done by robots

Comment: Was talking about the meat plant workers. They can be bred not to blab about what happens at work

Comment: "*You can go 100 stories underground*" by retaining a whole lot of rock for flooring and internal support.

Comment: @RonJohn bunkers have been built miles deep

Comment: If you can build a 100 story building, you can build a 100 story building in a 100 story deep hole. The 101 story is the only bit above ground

Comment: @user45751bunkers are caves.  This would not be a cave.

Comment: "*you can build a 100 story building in a 100 story deep hole.*"  You've got a point.  Not that it would go unnoticed... (construction equipment, removing the rock, bringing in the steel, concrete, drywall, elevators, etc, etc.)

Comment: @RonJohn and you have a point their but I can world build my way out of that hole, I just need a place where I can dig it... pun intended

Comment: Trucks enter and leave meat works all the time. If you tried to build everything at once, yes people would notice but over time, nobody would notice anything.

Comment: But it takes a **lot** of equipment to move **332 million meters^3** of rock, and then build inside that hole.

Comment: Who said you needed to do it all at once? There would be hundreds of truck movements a day and you could do it over many decades. Dig a new floor. Build a new floor. Dig a new floor. Build a new floor.

Comment: Also where should it be underground

Comment: Anywhere open and with low ground water so higher elevation places

Comment: Underground could include using a large part of a natural cave, which would save on time and resources.

Answer (score 3):

**Appalachian strip mine.**

http://www.plunderingappalachia.org/theissue.htm
[image: strip mine]

This method of mining entails removing a mountain, taking the coal, and putting what is left in the adjacent valley.

Your operators find an operation like this or preferably somewhere this has taken place recently.  Instead of filling the valley with mountain, put your facility there.  You will note to the public that environmental remediation is taking place in this strip mine site, and plant trees atop your building.  From the air it will look like forest. The Burj Khalifa is tall but an Appalachian valley is deep.

As regards loudness I recommend

1:  Acoustical tile.
2:  Morphine (also nice given that life is pain for these things).
3:  No visitors.